# Google Sheets API v.4 for PHP: exclude certain columns from $request

Tags: php, google-sheets, google-sheets-api

In this Google Sheet using the Sheets API, what's a simple example of excluding columns B and C from either retrieval from the Sheet during the request, or display via PHP?

Can columns B and C be excluded from the `$service` request?

Or, can columns B and C be excluded from display in the foreach loop?

Use R1C1 notation? Or majorDimension? https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets.values

[image]

```
// Usual suspects
require_once __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';
$googleAccountKeyFilePath = __DIR__ . '/service_key.json';
putenv('GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS=' . $googleAccountKeyFilePath);
$client = new Google_Client();
$client->useApplicationDefaultCredentials();
$client->addScope('https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets');
$service = new Google_Service_Sheets($client);
$spreadsheetId = '';
$response = $service->spreadsheets->get($spreadsheetId);
$spreadsheetProperties = $response->getProperties();

//The $range where columns could be excluded?

$range = 'Sheet1!A2:I';
$response = $service->spreadsheets_values->get($spreadsheetId, $range);
$values = $response->getValues();

//The foreach loop where columns could be excluded?

foreach($values as $val) {
$valuespan = "<span>".implode('</span> <span>', $val)."</span>";
echo $valuespan;
}
```

This is the output right now:

> Joe Null blah blah Smith 123 Dogpatch Lane Dog Town Alabama 34567
>
> John Blah Jones 456 Cat Hollow Cat Town Arkansas 12345
>
> Joe Not blah Johns 99 Cow Hollow Cow Town Arkansas 12345

Hoe can I exclude Columns B and C so I get:

> Joe Smith 123 Dogpatch Lane Dog Town Alabama 34567
>
> John Jones 456 Cat Hollow Cat Town Arkansas 12345
>
> Joe Johns 99 Cow Hollow Cow Town Arkansas 12345

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe your goal is as follows.

- You want to retrieve the values from Spreadsheet excluding the columns "B" and "C".
- You want to achieve this using googleapis for PHP.
- You have already been able to get values from Spreadsheet using Sheets API.

In this case, how about the following patterns?

### Pattern 1:

In this pattern, the method of "spreadsheets.values.get" is used. At first, the values are retrieved from "Sheet1!A2:I", and the result values can be retrieved by transposing.

#### From:

```php
$range = 'Sheet1!A2:I';
$response = $service->spreadsheets_values->get($spreadsheetId, $range);
$values = $response->getValues();
```

#### To:

```php
$range = 'Sheet1!A2:I';
$response = $service->spreadsheets_values->get($spreadsheetId, $range);
$transpose = array_map(null, ...$response->getValues());
array_splice($transpose, 1, 2);
$values  = array_map(null, ...$transpose);
```

### Pattern 2:

In this pattern, the method of "spreadsheets.values.batchGet" is used. At first, the values are retrieved from "Sheet1!A2:A" and "Sheet1!D2:I", and retrieved values are merged as an array.

#### From:

```php
$range = 'Sheet1!A2:I';
$response = $service->spreadsheets_values->get($spreadsheetId, $range);
$values = $response->getValues();
```

#### To:

```php
$response = $service->spreadsheets_values->batchGet($spreadsheetId, array('ranges' => ['Sheet1!A2:A', 'Sheet1!D2:I']));
$values = [];
foreach($response['valueRanges'][0]['values'] as $i => $v) {
    array_push($values, array_merge($v, $response['valueRanges'][1]['values'][$i]));
}
// In this case, you can retrieve the result values as "$values".
```

### References:

- [Method: spreadsheets.values.get](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets.values/get)
- [Method: spreadsheets.values.batchGet](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets.values/batchGet)

Comment: Thank you! Both methods work well. I can see the difference between the two.

Comment: @BlueDogRanch Thank you for replying and testing them. Both patterns use one API call. So please use one of them for your actual situation.

Answer (score 0):

As per documentation, **[spreadsheets.get](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets.values/get)** requests are not able to exclude defined ranges from the parameters, only include them.

Instead, you can use a **[spreadsheets.batchGet](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets.values/batchGet)** request so multiple ranges can be entered as parameters:

**Parameters:**

`ranges[]`    **string**

The A1 notation or R1C1 notation of the range to retrieve values from.

**Sample:**

```
$ranges = array('Sheet1!A2:A','Sheet1!D2:I');
$response = $service->spreadsheets_values->batchGet($spreadsheetId, $ranges);
```

The `response` is this object, in which you can iterate through the `ValueRange` array, for example `valueRange[i].values` to get the actual cell values.

```
{
  "spreadsheetId": string,
  "valueRanges": [
    {
      object (ValueRange)
    }
  ]
}
```

**Additional Reference:**

[Reading and Writing Values](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/guides/values)

Comment: Thanks, I found the docs, but I'm looking for an example(s).

Comment: Added a simple example on how to use ``spreadsheets.batchGet``

Comment: Thanks! Getting closer; I get the error Uncaught Google\Exception: (batchGet) unknown parameter: '0' in /google/src/Service/Resource.php:153